Matplotlib and latex fonts issue
I am working on figures and I am having trouble with fonts. In short, I want to make figures using latex rendering with a Helvetica/Helvetica Light font for text and some close font for equations. I have tried a few approaches and I think the most promising one is using 'pgf' backend. Please consider the following examples, maybe I'am missing something obvious.
First, I've tried to render text in latex.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{HelveticaNeue}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
Title 123. $123 \text{f}~\alpha~f~\mathbf{\alpha}$
\end{document}

Gives the following:

Note that bold alpha is not rendered, which I think is a major drawback of this approach. However, if I try to change HelveticaNeue to Helvetica or Helvetica Light xelatex fails to build. But Helvetica is present in Fonts folder which is a mystery to me.
% ls /System/Library/Fonts/ | grep Helvetica
Helvetica.ttc
HelveticaNeue.ttc

Then let's switch to matplotlib.
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.use('pgf')
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['pgf.preamble'] = r'''
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Helvetica Light}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}'''

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 2), layout='constrained', dpi=300)
ax.set_title(r'Title 123. $123 \text{f}~\alpha~f~\mathbf{\alpha}$')
f.savefig('1.pdf', backend='pgf')

gives the following:

Here I don't understand two things. The first is why Title 123 has a different font (DejavuSans, I guess). I've tried to change a few different settings in plt.rcParams but with no success. Also, I don't understand why (and where?) it finds Helvetica Light font. If I look in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist there are just Helvetica and HelveticaNeue.
Also, I have tried a different approach matplotlib+pdflatex. I used the following preamble:
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'''
            \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
            \usepackage{helvet}
            \usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}'''


In that case, matplotlib produced plots with Nimbus Sans L. instead of Helvetica, but otherwise it's more beneficial because at least it uses the same font inside and outside math-mode.
Any comments would be appreciated.

For the first issue, replace \mathbf{\alpha} with \boldsymbol{\alpha}.
